# Passing SQL query

Tags: mysql

I want to pass a query that gives output shown below from tblEmplyee.
How can I do that?

```
tblEmployee
 empID   empName   manId
  1        A        
  2        B        1
  3        C        2
```

```
Output
 name  Manager
  A       -
  B       A
  C       B
```

Comment: Do `SELF JOIN` on `empID`.

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Better title.

Answer (score 1):

**This is perfect**

Make use of `Right` and `self` joins

```
  select t2.empName, t1.empName as Manager from tblEmployee t1 
  right Join tblEmployee t2 on t1.empID = t2.manID
  order by empName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working and I got my mistake as well thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
      A.empName AS name, 
      B.empName AS Manager 
FROM tblEmployee A
LEFT JOIN tblEmployee B on A.empID=B.manID
```

Comment: Your welcome, atleast accept this as answer to close your question.^_^

Comment: @Rigel1121
Buddy; this will give an erroneous output.. :P
Did you check?